# Emacs company-css, where is the completion of css values?

Tags: init-file, completion, company-mode, auto-complete-mode, css

Company-mode completion seems a little weak in emacs. Is it my configuration?

Property completion seems simple enough:

```
strong {
  color: red;  /* <= color is the property */
}
```

Where red is the value in above, value completion is seemingly entirely absent? Comparatively, browser console gives every possible completion for a css value in the dropdown, while company-css suggests nothing?

Am I missing a backend? I'm using company-css and company-capf?

Does anyone have any suggested configuration for working css value completion in company?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd, both `company-css` (which you shouldn't use anymore if your Emacs version is 26 or newer) and `company-capf` offer `red` as the value completion in this example on my machine.

You might want to try `M-x company-diag` to verify which backend is actually being used.

CSS completion in Emacs is not perfect and won't reach the completeness of a browser, but it does offer completion for a lot of CSS property values.

Comment: I'm okay with company, it would be better with a more complete css backend. Describe-variable company-backends gives (company-css company-dabbrev company-capf company-dabbrev-code), for my scss and css modes. What backend would you recommend?

Comment: I recommend `company-capf`. And not putting `company-dabbrev` in front of it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is it possible to copy completion options from the browser console and paste them into company-css somewhere? I'm looking to get company to offer completion in css/scss after the first semi-colon after the first letter typed (set to 3 characters by default) with a dropdown of all possible completions for each css property. In my work flow, I'm usually googling properties to remember completion options, would be much much quicker to get a dropdown in that case. Seems it should not be difficult to achieve with emacs?

Comment: After the colon, you mean? It should work already. Try it with the default value of `company-backends`. And for "after the first letter", customize `company-minimum-prefix-length`.

Comment: As grateful as I am to David A. Moon for coming up with Emacs, the scss/css completion could be working smarter. Default backend settings or not, no company dropdown suggestions after position:, align-self:, align-items:, grid-template-columns: (which doesn't appear in any dropdown anyway), grid-row, etc. Company-mode, on the other hand, is totally great. Do you know how to add completion suggestion data to the company-css backend manually?

Comment: It's working better now. Not sure what changed. Only configured company-box and company-quickhelp, which had earlier commented out. That should not have made a difference though. Getting better selection in the dropdown now however.

Comment: Again: don't use `company-css`, use `company-capf`. You can take a look at `css-property-alist` and nearby constants for extending completion suggestions.

Comment: I'm glad it's working better for you now.